# Handling Poorly Annotated Objective-C Methods?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, annotations, nsurl, objective-c-nullability

It has been awhile since I've worked with Objective-C (and I'm brand new to Swift), so bear with me. However, I've noticed several "nullability annotations" that either don't make sense at all, or completely contradict Apple's documentation. Take the following `NSURL` class method for example:

```
+ (instancetype)URLByResolvingBookmarkData:(NSData *)bookmarkData 
                                   options:(NSURLBookmarkResolutionOptions)options 
                             relativeToURL:(NSURL *)relativeURL 
                       bookmarkDataIsStale:(BOOL *)isStale
                                     error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error;
```

You'll notice that there has been an annotation added to the `error` parameter, so one should assume this method has been annotated, right?

If that's the case, one would also assume that since the `relativeToURL` parameter has no nullability annotation added, it is *not* nullable.

Am I in fact understanding Objective-C's new nullability annotations?

If so, why does the documentation for `relativeURL` specifically state (bold formatting is mine):

> To resolve an app-scoped bookmark, use a value of **nil**.

I understand the reasoning behind the new annotations, but they have been so hit or miss with existing classes that I don't quite understand the good of them. Am I missing something?

Comment: You make a good case.  File a bug with Apple.  I think a lot of their annotations are done via automated tools.  It looks like you found a case that wasn't handled properly.

Answer (score 1):

If it says _Nonnull, it can't be nil.  If it says _Nullable, it can.  Otherwise, at least by default, you can't make any assumptions either way, IIRC.